# How to drop rows in Pandas dataframe by multiple criteria imposed on two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a toy example that captures my problem.  Any help please?  Thanks!

```
d = {'a': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
     'b': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Aiming for this result:

I want to drop two rows with (a,b) = (1,3) or (2,1).

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                       'b': [1,2,2,3,1,2,3]})
```

In reality, I would have an exclusion list that will be updated with time:
excl = [[1,3],[2,1],[3,4],........]

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Your solutions seem to work for me!

Answer (score 3):

This feels like firing a cannon when we should be able to just wave our hands, but:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'b': [1,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]})

excl = [[1, 3], [2, 1]]
keep = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(excl, columns=['a','b']),
                how='left', indicator=True)._merge == 'left_only'
```

gives me

```
In [91]: df.loc[keep]
Out[91]: 
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  2
5  2  2
6  2  3
7  3  1
8  3  2
9  3  3
```

(Note I added a duplicate 1,1 row for sanity purposes.)

Crazy method #2: use (effectively) a categorical encoding:

```
codes = pd.concat([df, edf], sort=False).groupby(["a","b"]).ngroup()
keep = ~codes.iloc[:len(df)].isin(codes.iloc[len(df):])
df = df.loc[keep]
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the list of "forbidden" rows into a dataframe with the column names different from the original dataframe:

```
to_drop = pd.DataFrame(excl, columns=('c','d')) # Different column names!
```

Merge the two dataframes. There will be `NaN`s where there is a mismatch:

```
combined = df.merge(to_drop, how='outer', left_on=['a','b'], right_on=['c','d'])
```

Take any column originally from the second dataframe, find out where the `NaN`s are, and use their indexes to extract valid rows from the first dataframe:

```
df[combined.isnull()['d']]
#   a  b
#0  1  1
#1  1  2
#4  2  2
#5  2  3
#6  3  1
#7  3  2
#8  3  3
```

You may see a warning:

> UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.

You can disregard it for now.

Answer (score 2):

Another little bit tricky solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'b': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]})
to_drop = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 1]})
result = df.merge(to_drop, on=['a', 'b'], how='outer', indicator=True) 
result = result[result['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop('_merge', axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  2
4  2  2
5  2  3
6  3  1
7  3  2
8  3  3
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will drop existing duplicates even if they're not in to_drop, won't it?

Comment: It will also add rows that would have been dropped but are not present in the original df.

Comment: Yeah....that could be a problem.  I could always go back to using nested for-loops, but given my data-set is relatively large, I am not sure if that's a good idea.

Comment: @KelvinYuen okay, check new solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tuple` with `isin`

```
df[~df.apply(tuple,1).isin([(1,3),(2,1)])]
Out[568]: 
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  2
4  2  2
5  2  3
6  3  1
7  3  2
8  3  3
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
result = df.loc[(df['a'] == 1 & df['b'] == 3) | (df['a'] == 2 & df['b'] == 1)]
```

Comment: The OP wants a more flexible solution.